# Conditionally replacing items with two lists

Tags: python, list, loops

I am trying to replace any '-' instances in list A with elements from list B in the same index. Right now my output does not modify list A at all, so I suspect my for loop is working with a copy.

```
A = [ ["dog", ["corgi",'-',"labrador"]], ["cat", ["tabby","persian",'-']] ]
B = ["BLANK 1","BLANK 2","BLANK 3"]
i = 0
for one,two in zip(A[i][1],B):
    if one == '-':
        one = two
    i += 1
print(A)
```

I want my output (i.e. modified list A) to look like this:

```
[ ["dog", ["corgi","BLANK 2","labrador"]], ["cat", ["tabby","persian","BLANK 3"]] ]
```

Many thanks for any guidance y'all can give me!

Comment: You've replaced the first and second '-'s by the second and third in your example output. Is this deliberate?

Comment: I think what the OP wants is to assign `BLANK 2` to every index 1 (so it's the second element), `BLANK 3` to index 2 (third element) and consequently `BLANK 1` to every index 0.

Comment: Ah, yes. Too many indices, I got confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `for` loop merely assigns the *values* from list created by `zip()` into the variables `one` and `two`.

Instead, you could do something like this:

```
for sublist in A:
    for index, value in enumerate(sublist[1]):
        if value == '-':
            sublist[1][index] = B[index]
```

This should work since lists are passed around by reference, and thus the `sublist` assigned by the outer `for` loop will still refer to the same lists as are referenced by `A`.

Comment: Should be `enumerate(sublist[1]))` and the assignment to "item" should actually be `sublist[1][index] = B[index]`

Comment: @mhawke ah, yeah, there's 3 levels of nesting there, not two. (so many braces...)

Answer (score 1):

In order to perform such a complex operation, we can break it down to simpler operations. At the simplest level, we want to replace the dash (-) with another string:

```
>>> x = 'corgi'
>>> y = 'BLANK 1'
>>> x if x != '-' else y
corgi

>>> x = '-'
>>> y = 'BLANK 2'
>>> x if x != '-' else y
BLANK 2
```

The next step is to replace `["corgi",'-',"labrador"]` with `["corgi",'BLANK 2',"labrador"]`:

```
>>> breed = ["corgi",'-',"labrador"]
>>> B = ["BLANK 1","BLANK 2","BLANK 3"]
>>> zip(breed, B)
[('corgi', 'BLANK 1'), ('-', 'BLANK 2'), ('labrador', 'BLANK 3')]
>>> [x if x != '-' else y for x, y in zip(breed, B)]
['corgi', 'BLANK 2', 'labrador']
```

Finally, we come to the big picture:

```
>>> C = [ [animal,
      [x if x != '-' else y for x, y in zip(breed, B)] ]
      for animal, breed in A]

>>> print C
[['dog', ['corgi', 'BLANK 2', 'labrador']], ['cat', ['tabby', 'persian', 'BLANK 3']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to zip over the whole list and then do the dereferencing inside the loop.

```
for a, b in zip(A, B):
    a[1] = [B[i] if v == '-' else v for i, v in enumerate(a[1])]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works improving your existing code a little bit

```
A = [ ["dog", ["corgi",'-',"labrador"]], ["cat", ["tabby","persian",'-']] ]
B = ["BLANK 1","BLANK 2","BLANK 3"]

i = 0
while i < 2:
    for ele in A[i][1]:
        if ele == '-':
            dashindex = A[i][1].index(ele)
            A[i][1][dashindex] = B[dashindex]
    i = i+1;
print(A)
```

Output:

> [['dog', ['corgi', 'BLANK 2', 'labrador']], ['cat', ['tabby', 'persian', 'BLANK 3']]]